# HTML controls in ASP pages

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET. When I was writing code in `.aspx` page I am trying to use HTML tag in it then i got the following error:

> *Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.*

Can any one suggest the solution for it? And how can I use those tags?

Comment: What control are you trying to add? How are you trying to add it (either in the markup or code behind)? Please update question to show the code which isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using master-page in that page, make sure all your html and server controls wrapped by Content Control.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
html......
</asp:Content>
```